# Django - tables2 STATIC URL not working

Tags: python, django

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html

I followed this tutorial to the point and managed to get tables to display BUT it's not loading CSS file. Instead of this(specified in HTML file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
```

it's only showing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
```

Here is my views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.template import RequestContext
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
from keywords.models  import Person
from keywords.tables  import PersonTable

def people(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'table': table})
```

Any idea what I am missing ?

**edit:** If I add this in mysite/urls then it loads css in source but displays: "bad operand type for unary +: 'list' error:

```
+ patterns('',
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
}),
```

)

**edit 2, tried a little different way:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/root/newproject/mysite/static_files/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files/"),    
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Did this to settings, and I am calling it with:

```
<link href="{% static 'screen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

It doesn't do anything, but if I change it to:

```
{{% static 'screen.css' %}}
```

Then it loads css but with this error:

*TemplateSyntaxError at /keywords/
Could not parse the remainder: '% static 'screen.css' %' from '% static 'screen.css' %'*

Comment: Have you configured `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py` file? See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL)

Comment: I tried changing it to a few different things but it never changes path in source file so I am thinking problem is probably with my views.py file(above)

Trying different options but nothing seems to work. 

If it helps, it's development "server"

Comment: With your first edit, you need to put the `+ patterns('', ..., )` **after** the URLPatterns.

Answer (score 2):

I used Ubuntu and the file screen.css is in

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css

then,

I changed

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
```

for

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
```

and it worked for me.

sorry for my English

Comment: I have the same issue, and when I add this last <link ..> line as mentioned above, it works here as well. So question is now why...  Using django 1.10.1 here. What version was used here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you `{% load staticfiles %}` before you used this variable?

Comment: Yes, that's at the top of the HTML. After that I changed the call:

  <link href="{% static 'screen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>

and here are my the settings:
###
    STATIC_ROOT = "/root/newproject/mysite/static_files/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files/"),    
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
###